js dialog won't show up in blazor web app
im trying to link my page's button with dialog that i have made before. it is a simple code, i have watched many tutorials and none of them solved mine
here's my code
page.razor
@page "/datapegawai"
@inject IJSRuntime js
@attribute [StreamRendering]

<PageTitle>Data Pegawai</PageTitle>

<h1>Data Pegawai</h1>


<div class ="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="header">
                    <button @onclick="ShowDialog" class="btn btn-primary float-end">
                        Add Product
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<DialogComponent>

</DialogComponent>

@code {
    private async Task ShowDialog()
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("myDialogFunction");
    }
}

dialog.js
window.myDialogFunction = function () {
    document.getElementById('my-dialog').showModal();
}

DialogComponent.razor

<div>

    <dialog id="my-dialog" @onclose="OnClose" @oncancel="OnCancel">
        <p>Hi Di sana!</p>
        <form method="dialog">
            <button>TUTUP!</button>
            <button>BATAL!</button>

        </form>
    </dialog>
</div>

@code {
    string message;
    void OnClose(EventArgs e) => message += "onclose,";
    void OnCancel(EventArgs e) => message += "oncancel,";
}

i have tried to add button to the DialogComponent.razor just to make sure the js worked. It did work, but i still have no idea how to connect my page.razor's button with the js. thank you

any errors in the browser developer tools console?

there is no error showed

So, I'm confused, which is the code that you are working with, and which is the code you added to make it work? does window.myDialogFunction actually get called?

Im working with the page.blazor (the onclick button). I have called myDialogFunction, yet it still didn’t appear

does window.myDialogFunction actually get called?

I believe the JavaScript function must be an exported function in order for it to work via JSRuntime.

@attribute [StreamRendering] means this is a statically rendered page.  There's no JSInterop.  The page needs to be interactively rendered.

In static render, button onclick event won't work. However you could use form submit as a replacement to make button submit work.
...
<div class="header">
    <button type="submit" form="form1">Add Product</button>
</div>
...
<form id="form1" method="post" @onsubmit="ShowDialog" @formname="form1">
    <AntiforgeryToken></AntiforgeryToken>
</form>

@code{
    private async Task ShowDialog()
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("myDialogFunction");
    }
}

Just note that the button element hasn't to be in the form element. Only make sure the buttom's form attribute equals to the corresponding form's id.
